# the number of the conjugacy class sizes of $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

If $a$ has the cycle
type $(k_1,k_2,...,k_t)$ and $b$ has the type $(l_1,l_2,...,l_t)$ which is different with the cycle
type of $a$, then can the equality $|C_{S_n}(a)|=|C_{S_n}(b)|$ occur?
I hope the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is yes: there is a bijection between the $n-2$ cycles and the permutations of type (n-2,2).

More generally, permutations of type $(k_1,k_2,\dots, k_t)$ are $\dbinom{n}{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_t}=\dfrac{n!}{k_1!\,k_2!\,\dotsm\, k_t!}$, *if you do not take into account permutations inside each cycle*. Hence the cardinal of a cojugation class is 
 $$\dfrac{\displaystyle n!\prod_{i=1}^t( k_i-1)}{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^t k_i!}.$$

Comment: Dear Bernard, thank you for your answer. Now what happen if n is even and $|C_{S_n}(a)|=2!(n/2)^2$. Then is the answer no?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help!